# live sound engineering with many vocals

Tags: vocals, microphone-technique

How do you mix vocals on a live show with so many microphones on stage?

[For example](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328221644/http://www.singers.com/group/images/Fermata-Town-sm.jpg), some groups could easily have as much as 14 microphones on the stage with various lead singers along the entire song.

What kind of stage mic management strategy could be used to prevent microphones getting mixed up between singers, etc.?

Comment: https://youtu.be/mhc32XmXsmQ?t=163

that is like probably 46 mics

Answer (score 2):

If there were only a few that were coming out with lead vocals i might keep those vocals to their own channels and then the others i might put together in subgroups. With a digital desk you could put compression on all channels so i would put compressors on everything but maybe let a little more through on the vocals singing lead and maybe put them together on a subgroup so you can control them by themselves and maybe 1 or 2 subgroups for the others

but the compressors would do most of the work to keep the leads in front with the backing vocals just under